# Disable TEXMFHOME for testing?

Tags: texmf

I'd like to be able to temporarily ignore my "home" texmf tree (in MacTeX `/Users/will/Library/texmf`) for testing purposes; e.g., to test some code and ensure only TeX Live-installed packages are found. Is this easily possible?

Comment: would `mv texmf texmf-something-else` be acceptable?

Comment: @Andrew: That's the way I do it (`mv ~/texmf ~/texmf_`) :-). However, maybe using `export TEXMFHOME=""` will overwrite the internal definition of TEXMFHOME?

Comment: A similar suggestion to that of @AndrewStacey's is to keep your "home" texmf tree wherever and create a symbolic link to it via `/Users/will/Library/texmf`. Then you can manipulate that link whenever you want to disable TEXMFHOME. This might be somewhat safer than using `mv`. Also you could create a script that when invoked if the TEXMFHOME is enabled disables it, and if it's disables, enables it.

Comment: `unset TEXMFHOME`

Comment: Testing on my system shows that you need to set TEXMFHOME to *something*, but that that something need not exist.  So `export TEXMFHOME=$HOME/a-nonexistant-directory` works.

Comment: @Herbert: `unset TEXMFHOME` (as well as `export TEXMFHOME=""`) only works if `TEXMFHOME` has been explicitly set (and exported) by the user. It doesn't work if `TEXMFHOME` has the “implicit” default value set in `texmf.cnf`.

Comment: My experiment showed that if the TEXMFHOME directory is in the standard place then `unset TEXMFHOME` doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment, and the formatting would be restrictive.  Here's what happens on my (Linux) system:

```
~% echo $TEXMFHOME

~% kpsewhich mymacros.sty
/home/stacey/texmf/tex/latex/bzr/mymacros.sty
~% export TEXMFHOME=""
~% kpsewhich mymacros.sty
/home/stacey/texmf/tex/latex/bzr/mymacros.sty
~% export TEXMFHOME=$HOME/a-nonexistant-directory
~% kpsewhich mymacros.sty                        
(1)~%
~% unset TEXMFHOME
~% kpsewhich mymacros.sty
/home/stacey/texmf/tex/latex/bzr/mymacros.sty
~%
```

So the one that works reliably is to set `TEXMFHOME` to something that doesn't exist.  (You could set it to something that does exist, but then you run the risk of there being something TeX might look for in that directory.)

Comment: Thanks! I tried setting `TEXMFHOME=""` myself and when that failed asked here :)

Comment: This is what I do.  I have a testing texmf directory, and a TeXShop engine script that sets TEXMFHOME to that directory.  If that directory is empty, then you'll get only TL stuff.

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to use a directory other than the default directory for the personal `texmf` tree (the latter is set in `texmf.cnf`). If I want the personal `texmf` tree to be ignored I simply invoke `latex` (in a Bash shell) like

```
TEXMFHOME="" latex mydoc.tex
```

Comment: So it would seem that if TEXMFHOME is unset *or* is empty then TeX uses the standard location (most likely `$HOME/texmf`).  So this works if ones home texmf tree is in a non-standard place.  Mine works for the standard place, so between us that's everything covered!

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Yes, in your case, you would simply pass `TEXMFHOME=<non-existing-directory>` to the subshell in which `latex` is executed.